# Q How does HPX fair vs 'apache cloud computing' (e.g. vs spark)?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-flink, hpx

I have been looking at HPX (https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx) as a potential mechanism for making applications more scalable.

I believe HPX is primarily targeted at (and therefore optimised for) the HPC community who typically have clusters of 
nodes with many code with fast interconnects between them. 
The parallelX model doens't require this but of course your performance will degrade due to the higher cost of passing data between nodes.

On the other end of the spectrum we have a suite of Java frameworks including hadoop, spark & flink. These come out of the commercial community and addressing different sorts of workload.

So what's in it if you were choosing between them (ignoring C++ vs Java flamewars)

If considering purely on performance grounds how do they compare in terms of overheads?

Granted it depends heavily on the kind of problem you are trying to solve.
I'd like to understand the trade-offs better.

Comment: It is really not a SO type of question...

Comment: I think it is as I'm looking for considerations as to whether to develop an app using HPX or Spark. Where else would you ask that?

Comment: I guess [Quora](http://quora.com/) could be a good place. You could try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but I am pretty sure it doesn't meet the criteria.

Comment: Quora are you stark raving mad! I think Joel would climb into a coffin just to turn over! :)

Comment: That was my idea :) Seriously though StackExchange sites are highly opinionated when it comes to content but Spark has user list and ste||ar has irc channel. Given there are 6 questions including yours tagged with hpx I kind of doubt you'll get your answer here even if it won't be downvoted and deleted.

Comment: Granted HPX is quite new. Still perhaps my question is ahead of the curve if it takes off?

Comment: Actually Ste||ar recommend asking questions *here* on S/O :) 
https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx

Comment: Well, its been public longer than Spark. But fundamentally it is looks like much more specialized tool and takes is focused on (correct me if I'm wrong) on task parallelization not data parallelism.

Comment: I doesn't make this particular question more on-topic :)

Comment: Why is this question about HPX vs, any different from similar questions (which are not closed as off topic) for flink vs spark or flink vs storm? E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699119/what-is-are-the-main-differences-between-flink-and-storm
or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780747/apache-flink-vs-apache-spark-as-platforms-for-large-scale-machine-learning?rq=1

Comment: It is not. And same as before it doesn't make any of these more on-topic IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

HPX has not been used or adapted to cloud-type scenarios at this point. We have thought about adapting it, but have not implemented anything. It would be possible (in principle, as you noted as well), though.

Comment: I see. So I guess no-one attempt as has been made to compare things yet. What kind of adaptations does your team have in mind?
Is it primarily to optimise for slow interconnects between nodes or is the something more fundamental involved?

Comment: First of all we would need to create a special networking layer (for instance on top of websockets). Some additional security considerations would apply as well. Everything else would be up to the application, I guess.

Comment: I'm not clear why you woudl need a layer based on websockets. What is wrong with using unix sockets and TCP as normal? Is it to avoid the need to open ports in the firewall manually? I can see that would make sense.

Comment: Yes, firewall issues, mostly. Security is another concern.

Comment: Has the situation changed in the years since this was answered?